# Profit Function with Unique Optimal Solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

With in a feasible region does there exist a profit function that has unique optimal solution and if so it also a basic feasible solution?

Comment: For the first question, I know it's yes, but I don't know how to write this rigorously.  As long as the objective function is "parallel" to the bounding hyperplanes, you have uniqueness of optimal solution.  For the second question, it's exactly the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Programming.

Comment: Could give a wordy description of the proof or a starting point that I can work with for the first part .

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76603/linear-programming-uniqueness-of-optimal-solution